# CentOS MySQL install

Tags: centos, mysql

I am very new to Linux and I am having trouble with MySQL on CentOS.

I got myself a CentOS virtual server. I would like to move a few WordPress sites from my dedicated Windows Server (too expensive and wasn't making use of it) onto the CentOS server.

So I need Apache, MySQL and PHP. I installed Apache fine, but installing MySQL is proving to be more difficult!

I keep reading that CentOS is now friends with MariaDb, but I've never heard of MariaDb. I just know that WordPress is MySQL's friend!

How do I install MySQL on CentOS version `7.4.1708 (Core)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MariaDB is a fork, binary compatible, of MySql so you don't need MySql on your Centos. Even the MySql Workbench is compatible with MariaDB without any restriction or limitation.

After Oracle bought Sun Microsystems they modified the license of MySql then MariaDB was created. You can find more information about [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_acquisition_by_Oracle#MySQL_petition_and_forks) and [here](https://mariadb.org/).

Comment: So for all intents and purposes, I could just think of MariaDB as the new name for MySQL? WordPress MySQL export > then import to MariaDB would all work just fine (same commands ...etc)?

Comment: @Ciwan exactly. It's like a rename but this new name it's still strictly open source. Even in bash you call to the mysql command to connect, not mariadb or something like that.